# How to delete records from data using Springs named parameter JDBC template update?

Tags: java, spring, sybase, spring-jdbc

I have below query o delete records from **SYBASE** database. I am using Spring NamedParameterJDBCTemplete

String query = "Delete FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ID IN (:ids)"

Have written below function to delete records

```
    void deleteRecords(List<ID> ids){
       SqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource("ids", ids);
       try{
          namedParameterJDBCTemplate.update(query, parameters)
       }
       catch(Exception e){
       }
    }
```

I keep getting error below

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar **[Delete from PRODUCTS WHERE ID IN ()]; nested exception is com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Incorrect syntax near ')'**

Comment: can you set the log level of the underlying org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate to DEBUG to see the exact executed query?

Comment: Could you post your query and parameters you are supplying?